# How to add link to show action of the relation entity on relation field in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, php-7.3, symfony-4.3

Im making admin panel in SonataAdminBundle.
In User show action i have field companies which return array of companies assigned to the user.
It is a OneToMany relation. UserCompany has user_id and company_id.
I want to create link on each returned company name, which points to it's entity show action.
This is code from configureShowFields() function in UserAdmin class:

```
                ->with('Assigned organizers',['class' => 'col-md-6'])
                    ->add('companies', null, [
                        'label' => 'Organizers',
                    ])
                ->end()
```

I managed to create a link on a string field pointing to show action of an entity, but the id property is taken from the current entity view:

```
            ->with('Address', ['class' => 'col-md-6'])
                ->add('userProfile.locality', 'url', [
                    'route' => [
                        'name' => 'admin_app_employee_show',
                        'identifier_parameter_name' => 'id'
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Localiy',
                ])
```

What's more Sonata Admin create links on related fields, when the relation is direct, 
for example: 
Company has many Employee. Then in Company show action on employees field 
I see array with links already heading to edit action of Employee entty.

Maybe there is a possibility to override template for this field, but it seems unclear for me, 
as the documentation lacks of more advanced examples.
This is how I tried to test overriding the template of a field:

```
                ->add('userProfile.street', null, array(
                    'label' => 'Street',
                    'template' => 'custom-field.html.twig',
                ))
```

Location of the template: App/templates/Admin/

Any help appreciated

Comment: SonataAdmin generated link to these fields, when I added UserCompany entity to sonata_admin.yaml, and configured it as UserCompanyAdmin,  which is a connector between Company and User. But links point to the edit view of UserCompany. How to assign route_name value in the show_one_to_many.html.twig template ? Or in configureShowFields ?

Answer (score 0):

SonataAdmin automatically creates links to related entities once it has all of them configured and added to services. 
Then you can just change the route action of the link on the relation field as following:

```
            ->with('Assigned events', ['class' => 'col-md-6'])
                ->add('events', null, [
                    'route' => [
                        'name' => 'show'
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Events',
                ])
            ->end()
```

You can also change the type of relation field eg.'many_to_one' instead of *null* which might help in some cases.